# reach a webservice on a java angular project deployed on jetty 9.4.12

Tags: web-services, jetty

I have a java angular project that I deploy on jetty 9.4.12

Here is my web.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Tourism Applicationwith Angular</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application with a source code organization
        based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>

   <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
  </listener>



      <resource-env-ref>
        <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
      </resource-env-ref>    

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>webservice.TourismWebService</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>  
        <param-name>resteasy.injector.factory</param-name>  
        <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory</param-value>  
    </context-param> 

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is my web service

```java
package webservice;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;


import business.TourismBusinessService;
import dto.SearchPathDto;
import dto.TourismPathDto;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;


@Path("/tourism")
@Api(value = "analyses", description = "search path by userId, location and max distance")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TourismWebService extends Application {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;



    @Inject
    private TourismBusinessService tourismBusinessService;

    @GET
    @Path("searchPath/{userId}/{longitude}/{latitude}/{distanceMax}")
    @ApiOperation("Get analysis by Id")
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK")
    public Response searchPath(@PathParam("userId") long userId,@PathParam("longitude") double longitude,@PathParam("latitude") double latitude,@PathParam("distanceMax") double distanceMax) {
        SearchPathDto responseDto = new SearchPathDto();
        //org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory test = new org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory();
        List<TourismPathDto> tourismPathDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        TourismPathDto tourismPathDto1 = new TourismPathDto();
        tourismPathDto1.setCategoryId(1);
        tourismPathDto1.setDistance((double)100);
        tourismPathDto1.setLongitude(2.3313926);
        tourismPathDto1.setLatitude(48.873278);
        tourismPathDto1.setRoot("root1");
        tourismPathDto1.setLeaf("leaf1");
        tourismPathDto1.setWeight((double)2);
        tourismPathDto1.setMark((double)3);
        tourismPathDtoList.add(tourismPathDto1);
        TourismPathDto tourismPathDto2 = new TourismPathDto();
        tourismPathDto2.setCategoryId(2);
        tourismPathDto2.setDistance((double)200);
        tourismPathDto2.setLongitude(2.3368291);
        tourismPathDto2.setLatitude(48.8747394);
        tourismPathDto2.setRoot("root2");
        tourismPathDto2.setLeaf("leaf2");
        tourismPathDto2.setWeight((double)3);
        tourismPathDto2.setMark((double)4);
        tourismPathDtoList.add(tourismPathDto2);

        responseDto.setDistanceMax(distanceMax);
        responseDto.setLatitude(latitude);
        responseDto.setLongitude(longitude);
        responseDto.setUserId(userId);
        responseDto.setTourismPathDtoList(tourismPathDtoList);
        //SearchPathDto responseDto = tourismBusinessService.getTourismPathList(userId, longitude, latitude, distanceMax);
        if (responseDto == null)
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        return Response.ok(responseDto).build();
    }

}
```

I ran jetty : java -jar start.jar

But when I try to reach the following web service

```
http://localhost:8080/tourism-services/tourism/searchPath/1/2.3313926/48.873278/200
```

I have a 
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /tourism-services/tourism/searchPath/1/2.3313926/48.873278/200. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

error

Thank you for your help

Here is the continuation......
the jetty.xml that I modified is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Documentation of this file format can be found at:              -->
<!-- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/       -->
<!--                                                                 -->
<!-- Additional configuration files are available in $JETTY_HOME/etc -->
<!-- and can be mixed in. See start.ini file for the default         -->
<!-- configuration files.                                            -->
<!--                                                                 -->
<!-- For a description of the configuration mechanism, see the       -->
<!-- output of:                                                      -->
<!--   java -jar start.jar -?                                        -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Configure a Jetty Server instance with an ID "Server"           -->
<!-- Other configuration files may also configure the "Server"       -->
<!-- ID, in which case they are adding configuration to the same     -->
<!-- instance.  If other configuration have a different ID, they     -->
<!-- will create and configure another instance of Jetty.            -->
<!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.server.Server for all              -->
<!-- configuration that may be set here.                             -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Arg name="threadpool"><Ref refid="threadPool"/></Arg>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Add shared Scheduler instance                               -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler"/>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Ref refid="DeploymentManager">
    <Call name="addLifeCycleBinding">
      <Arg>
        <New
          class="org.eclipse.jetty.cdi.servlet.WeldDeploymentBinding">
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Ref>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Http Configuration.                                         -->
    <!-- This is a common configuration instance used by all         -->
    <!-- connectors that can carry HTTP semantics (HTTP, HTTPS, etc.)-->
    <!-- It configures the non wire protocol aspects of the HTTP     -->
    <!-- semantic.                                                   -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- This configuration is only defined here and is used by      -->
    <!-- reference from other XML files such as jetty-http.xml,      -->
    <!-- jetty-https.xml and other configuration files which         -->
    <!-- instantiate the connectors.                                 -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.server.HttpConfiguration       -->
    <!-- for all configuration that may be set here.                 -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
      <Set name="secureScheme"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme" default="https" /></Set>
      <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.securePort" deprecated="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
      <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputBufferSize" deprecated="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
      <Set name="outputAggregationSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize" deprecated="jetty.output.aggregation.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion" deprecated="jetty.send.server.version" default="true" /></Set>
      <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendDateHeader" deprecated="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
      <Set name="headerCacheSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize" default="4096" /></Set>
      <Set name="delayDispatchUntilContent"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.delayDispatchUntilContent" deprecated="jetty.delayDispatchUntilContent" default="true"/></Set>
      <Set name="maxErrorDispatches"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.maxErrorDispatches" default="10"/></Set>
      <Set name="blockingTimeout"><Property deprecated="jetty.httpConfig.blockingTimeout" name="jetty.httpConfig.blockingTimeout.DEPRECATED" default="-1"/></Set>
      <Set name="persistentConnectionsEnabled"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.persistentConnectionsEnabled" default="true"/></Set>
      <Set name="cookieCompliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.CookieCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.cookieCompliance" default="RFC6265"/></Arg></Call></Set>
      <Set name="multiPartFormDataCompliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.MultiPartFormDataCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.multiPartFormDataCompliance" default="RFC7578"/></Arg></Call></Set>
    </New>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set the default handler structure for the Server            -->
    <!-- A handler collection is used to pass received requests to   -->
    <!-- both the ContextHandlerCollection, which selects the next   -->
    <!-- handler by context path and virtual host, and the           -->
    <!-- DefaultHandler, which handles any requests not handled by   -->
    <!-- the context handlers.                                       -->
    <!-- Other handlers may be added to the "Handlers" collection,   -->
    <!-- for example the jetty-requestlog.xml file adds the          -->
    <!-- RequestLogHandler after the default handler                 -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
         <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
           <Item>
             <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
           </Item>
         </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- extra server options                                        -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="stopAtShutdown"><Property name="jetty.server.stopAtShutdown" default="true"/></Set>
    <Set name="stopTimeout"><Property name="jetty.server.stopTimeout" default="5000"/></Set>
    <Set name="dumpAfterStart"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpAfterStart" deprecated="jetty.dump.start" default="false"/></Set>
    <Set name="dumpBeforeStop"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop" deprecated="jetty.dump.stop" default="false"/></Set>

</Configure>
```

In this file, I added the following

```
<Ref refid="DeploymentManager">
<Call name="addLifeCycleBinding">
  <Arg>
    <New
      class="org.eclipse.jetty.cdi.servlet.WeldDeploymentBinding">
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

and I added this dependency to maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
</dependency>
```

But I got this error

```
MBP-de-Admin:jetty-distribution-9.4.12.v20180830 admin$ java -jar start.jar
2019-02-06 07:49:05.745:INFO::main: Logging initialized @841ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-02-06 07:49:05.912:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <Ref refid="DeploymentManager"><Call name="addLifeCycleBinding"><Arg>|        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.cdi.servlet.WeldDeploymentBinding"/>|      </Arg></Call></Ref> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No object for refid=DeploymentManager in file:/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/Jetty/jetty-distribution-9.4.12.v20180830/etc/jetty.xml
2019-02-06 07:49:05.913:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No object for refid=DeploymentManager
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.refObj(XmlConfiguration.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
```

Comment: Any errors from the server side logs?

Comment: Also, have you setup the jetty xml to allow weld/CDI to work with your webapp?  If so, can you show your configuration in your question?

Comment: Hello Joakim, I added the information you need (jetty.xml modified, added dependency) and the error I got. Could you have a look at it and help me ? Thank you